# MERGE with 3+ relations coming from single node

Tags: merge, neo4j, cypher

I'm looking for a way to create (or if exist, find a matching pattern) for `MERGE` with 3 and more relationships coming out from single node.

I know how to find/create 2 nodes related to single node, for example:

```
MERGE (f1:Friend)
MERGE (f2:Friend)
MERGE (w2)<-[:HAS_FRIEND]-(p:Person)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(w1)
ON CREATE {do something}
ON MATCH SET {do something else}
```

I understand that you can continue creating/finding more nodes if you add them to right-most or left-most nodes, e.g.

```
MERGE (friend1)<-[:HAS_FRIEND]-(p:Person)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(friend2)-[:HAS_PET]->(pet:Pet)-[:HAS_TOY]->(toy:Toy)
```

But how to `MERGE` (find if WHOLE pattern exists or create it if not found) something like 3 `:Friend` nodes coming out of single `:Person` node

[image: 3 nodes related to 1 node]

Comment: You should study the [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) docs. Your current understanding is flawed, and your example Cypher code has a lot of problems. For example,  `MERGE (f1:Friend) MERGE (f2:Friend)` will never create 2 `Friend` nodes -- even if none existed beforehand. Also, a `MERGE` pattern with multiple relationships will result in *creation* of the entire pattern if only part of the pattern can be matched -- so should be avoided. And it's impossible to use "ON MATCH" and "ON CREATE" that way, since a single `MERGE` cannot do everything you want.

Comment: Also, one would normally use the same `Person` label for all people nodes. (But I guess there can be special use cases where it makes sense to use 2 different labels.)

Answer (score 4):

Not completely sure I follow, but is something like this what you are looking for? Given a list of friends and me merge each `Person/Friend` mode and then merge the relationship between them as `[:FRIEND].

```
with ['dave','mary','derek'] as friends
merge (me:Person {name: 'me'})
with me, friends
unwind friends as friend
merge (f:Friend {name: friend})
merge (me)-[:FRIEND]->(f)
return *
```

If you had a friendship going the other way though and you did not want to create a new relationship in the other direction a second time through you could guard against that with something like this. Say we introduce *me's* good friend *rich* into the equation but rich is actually friends in the other direction.

```
merge (me:Person {name: 'me'})
merge (rich:Friend {name: 'rich'})
merge (me)<-[:FRIEND]-(rich)
return *
```

Then if we add rich to the list we are trying to merge but add a step after each `:Friend` is merged to guard against creating one if it already exists in the other direction.

```
with ['dave','mary','derek','rich'] as friends
merge (me:Person {name: 'me'})
with me, friends
unwind friends as friend
merge (f:Friend {name: friend})
with me, f
match (f)
where not (me)<-[:FRIEND]-(f)
merge (me)-[:FRIEND]->(f)
return *
```

The `match (f) where not (me)<-[:FRIEND]-(f)` guards against `merging` the relationship if it already exists albeit in the other direction.

It prevents this from happening

[image: friends with bi-directional FRIEND relationship]

Comment: Let me use your example to further explain what I'm trying to do. I want to have 2 separate actions. Found match means that  `:Person` has `:FRIENDs` dave, mary and derek. 

Unsuccessful match is e.g. `:Person` has only dave and mary as `:FRIENDs` but not derek.

If match was successful than do actions defined in `ON MATCH SET`, if not than do actions defined in `ON CREATE SET`.

Comment: As far as I understand, your query doesn't check it. For 2 friends you could write `MERGE` in following way (pseudo-code): `(dave:Friend)<-[:FRIEND]-(me:Person)-[:FRIEND]->(mary:Friend)` but I have no idea how to add to this query `-[:FRIEND]->(derek:Friend)`

Comment: I think I get it, no, my query does not check first but that is the beauty of `MERGE`, i don't have to.  If the net result is `:Person` connected to all three `:Friends` `MERGE` does the dirty work for you.  It will return *me*   connected to all three regardless if they are already connected. This query can be run over and over and will yield the same result. If you wanted to check first you could but it would be redundant because at the end you are going to still create it.

Comment: I just thought of a scenario where you would may want to guard against the merge : if the relationship already exists in the other direction.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that's great piece of knowledge! Unfortunately it still doesn't help to solve my case. The difference between your query and mine is that if e.g. with query `MERGE (dave:Friend)<-[:FRIEND]-(me:Person)-[:FRIEND]->(mary:Friend‌​)` if I'd somehow add another `-[:FRIEND]->(rich:Friend)` than it would create new node `(rich:Friend)` and another instance of `:Person`, it would also relate it to (existing friends) dave, mary and newly created rich. In your query it wouldn't create new node `:Person` and it would connect existing `(me:Person)` and to newly created node rich.

Comment: In other words: If all friends in `MERGE` don't match existing `:Person` than new `:Person` should be created with new relations to existing/new `:Friend`s

Comment: Do you find solution? If yes can you please add it as answer for you own question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `ON CREATE` and `ON MATCH` in the way you envision, as that would require you to somehow craft a *single* [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) clause that could safely and completely handle the rest of your complex use case. That is not possible.

The sample query below shows how to handle your use case (as far as I understand it).

Assumptions:

- The name of the "me" person is passed in the `myName` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/).
- The list of friend names is passed in the `names` parameter.
- All people nodes have the `Person` label.
- At most one `HAS_FRIEND` relationship should exist between a pair of `Person` nodes. (Notice that the `(p)-[:HAS_FRIEND]-(f)` pattern does not specify a relationship direction, so it will match either direction.)
- You are running neo4j 4.x+.

The following query ensures that all the people whose names are in the `$names` list are connected (in either direction) to the person whose name is given by `$myName`. It will also conditionally perform the equivalent of "ON CREATE" or "ON MATCH" processing (except on steroids, since you are not limited to `SET` clauses), depending on whether the query had to create new nodes.

```
MATCH (me:Person {name: $myName})
WITH me, [(me)-[:HAS_FRIEND]-(f) WHERE f.name IN $names | f] AS foundFriends
CALL {
  WITH me, foundFriends
  UNWIND [x IN $names WHERE NOT x IN [ff IN foundFriends | ff.name] | x] AS neededName
  CREATE (me)-[:HAS_FRIEND]->(newFriend:Person {name: neededName})
  RETURN COLLECT(newFriend) AS newFriends
}
CALL apoc.do.when(
  SIZE(newFriends) > 0,
  'RETURN "CREATED" AS result',
  'RETURN "MATCHED" AS result',
  {me: me, foundFriends: foundFriends, newFriends: newFriends}) YIELD value
RETURN value.result
```

This query uses the [CALL subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/) syntax introduced in neo4j 4.0.

And it also uses the APOC procedure [apoc.do.when](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/cypher-execution/conditionals/) to conditionally process Cypher code (to do something like "ON CREATE" or "ON MATCH" processing). In the sample above, the Cypher code simply returns "CREATED" or "MATCHED". But your actual code could be much more complicated (and also make use of the parameters passed via the `{me: me, foundFriends: foundFriends, newFriends: newFriends}` argument).